# Get Value and pass as parameter to function in Java

Tags: java, json, httpresponse, http-method

```
 ResponseEntity<String> respEntity = null;
        try {
            respEntity = getConfiguredRestTemplate().exchange(uri.toString()
                    , HttpMethod.GET
                    , entity
                    , new ParameterizedTypeReference<String>() {
                    });
            log.debug("URL to retrieve a document : {}", respEntity.getBody());
}
```

The respEntity.getBody() returns {"url":"https://aps-fst"}

I want to send only the value - https://aps-fst as parameter to a function to download the content in the URL. How to extract only the URL value and pass it as parameter of type  URL / String  ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to parse JSON in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591098/how-to-parse-json-in-java). It is called JSON parsing. Check the link i shared for the information.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
  String jsonString = respEntity.getBody();
   JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(jsonString);
   String s3urlvalue = obj.getString("url");
   log.debug("S3 URL  to retrieve a document : {} ", s3urlvalue);
```

I am able to get value with above code

Answer (score 0):

You can use ObjectMapper from jackson and have the response body transformed into a map from which you can take the url value. You can find an example [here](https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-convert-java-map-to-from-json-jackson/).